# i unable to convert JSObject of API key

Tags: json, api

i am using the APi of https://openweathermap.org/current
 
i want to get particular **weather** part from the API as below my code  so i am using JSON

Here below link is API key where i want weather part 

http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1

**Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject**

I am using the AsyncTask

My MainActivity is here

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String data ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadWeatherData downloadWeatherData = new DownloadWeatherData();

    try {

      downloadWeatherData.execute("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1").get();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is my java file

public class DownloadWeatherData extends AsyncTask {

```
String weatherdata;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

        int data = inputStreamReader.read();

        while(data!=-1)
        {
            char str = (char)data;
            weatherdata+=str;

            data = inputStreamReader.read();
        }

        return weatherdata;

    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    super.onPostExecute(s);


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        String info = jsonObject.getString("weather");
        Log.d("weatherpart",info);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think retrofit is the HttpURLConnection alternative

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. **Weather** is an array not a **json** object. Do it like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(s);

JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("weather");
int length = ja_data.length();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: i had remove the try and catch block even also same error is showing as above